# How to read a xml file with python with xml.dom

Tags: xml-parsing, python-3.6

i am having one xml file and i need to fetch value of tags postnumer and regarding every postnumber all the valid number values...i am using xml.dom for reading xml file in python what is the code to fetch the value...how can i do this? please help

xml code:

```
    -<post>
     <PostNumber>180</postNumber>
    -<validList>
     <validNumber>208</validNumber>
     <validNumber>209</validNumber>
     <validNumber>210</validNumber>
     </validlist>
     </post>

    -<post>
    <postNumber>1023832</postNumber>
    -<validlist>
     <validNumber>264</validNumber>
     <validNumber>401</validNumber>
     </validlist>
     </post>
```